# C#: Forcing TLS1.2 but Https server still giving common algorithm error

Tags: c#, ssl, https

Im trying to setup a simple HTTPS web server using TcpClient, SslStream, and a self signed certificate.

The code starts fine, displays waiting for client, but when I connect to it via a web browser I get

> "A call to SSPI failed, The client and server cannot communicate,
>   because they do not possess a common algorithm"

From what I have read, this typically means that the server is trying to use a protocol type that the client doesnt have or cannot use (IE: outdated), and many say to make sure that both the server and client are using TLS 1.2.

-I have made sure to include `"ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12"` to force tls1.2, and am using Firefox(and others) which I have verified are up to date and work with tls12.

-Im on .net 4.7, so that shouldnt be an issue I dont think.

-I have manually imported the certificate into firefox.

-I have tried allowing all protocols, and no protocols, and "default"

-I have gone into the registry and enabled all TLS, and disabled all but tls1.2, both with same result.

Im sure this has been answered before, but I have been scouring SO and google for a couple days now, so I give up, roast away!

> static X509Certificate serverCertificate = null;

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;  //Force tls 1.2
    MakeCert();                                                         //Create self signed certificate and assign to serverCertificate
    SslTcpServer.RunServer();
    return 0;
}

static void MakeCert()
{
    var ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(); // generate asymmetric key pair
    var req = new CertificateRequest("cn=localhost", ecdsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
    var cert = req.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(5));

    // Create PFX (PKCS #12) with private key
    string pfxPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "mycert.pfx");
    File.WriteAllBytes(pfxPath, cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "Password"));
    // Create Base 64 encoded CER (public key only)
    string cerPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "mycert.cer");
    File.WriteAllText(cerPath,
        "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n"
        + Convert.ToBase64String(cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert), Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks)
        + "\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----");

    string keyfilename = "mycert.pfx";
    string certpath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, keyfilename);
    X509Certificate certificate = new X509Certificate2(certpath, "Password");
    serverCertificate = certificate;
}

public static void RunServer()
{
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8080);
    listener.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client to connect...");
        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        ProcessClient(client);
    }
}

static void ProcessClient(TcpClient client)
{
    SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false);
    try
    {
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate, clientCertificateRequired: false, enabledSslProtocols : SslProtocols.Tls12, checkCertificateRevocation: false);
        Console.WriteLine("Authenticated");
    }
    catch (AuthenticationException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
        if (e.InnerException != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
        sslStream.Close();
        client.Close();
        return;
    }
    finally
    {
        sslStream.Close();
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

Code never reaches "Authenticated", always throws exception

> "A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception"

with inner exception

> "The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess
>   a common algorithm"

Comment: AFAIR .Net uses schannel lib of Windows for TLS communication. Therefore the Windows version determines which cipher suites and tls modes are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is not about SSL/TLS protocols. It's about the signature algorithm ECDsa. It looks as if `nistP521` (the default curve used by `ECDsa.Create`) is not supported by Firefox (I didn't check any documentation) as it works perfectly with nistP256 or nistP384

```
  var ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP384); // generate asymmetric key pair
  var req = new CertificateRequest("cn=localhost",ecdsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
```